# require scopes between required functions

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access functions from a exported js file.
so on top of my main app.js file I require this file like this:

```
var api = require("./plugins/apis.js”);
```

I can call the functions from this file but not inside other var 
functions, even if I send api as a parameter like

```
/**
 * @param access_token your access token from your instance settings page
 * @param [options] json object to be passed to the external web service. Can include any of 'context', 'verbose', 'n'
 * @param callback callback that takes 2 arguments err and the response body
 */


var getData = function (access_token, options, callback) {
   if(!callback) {
        callback = options;
        options = undefined;
    }
// do stuff
}

function init(api) {
    var information = getData(ACCESS_TOKEN, function (err, res) {
        init(api)
        // do stuff, but calls from apis.js functions not available.
```

I don’t want to require this recursively, but I need this inside my getData function without being out of scope.
I don't know how to use the callback. Can someone explain how to use callback and have functions from the external apis.js functions available at the same time?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you remove `.js` from the call to `require`? And is all this code inside `app.js`?

Comment: I don't see a problem doing that. We need more information in order to understand why you get this behaviour.  Can you provide the implementation of the getData function and the api.js module?

Answer (score 2):

Within your example callback function from getData, the `api` variable is being overridden by the callback's own `api` parameter. So you would at least need to give it a unique name if you want to access the `api` you `require`ed:

```
var api = require("./plugins/apis”);

var information = getData(ACCESS_TOKEN, function (err, res, _api) {
  // do stuff
  // _api was passed here from getData()
  // api is still the object pulled in from your call to require()
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but api.dostuff() don't work inside getData dispite no errors shown. If I use the exact same function call outside getData, it runs as expected. Is this because I am calling a syncronous function?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Does anything within the callback function get executed? Make sure that your `getData` function invokes the callback. If you want to start a new question and link to it here I'll take a look.